# Modal with unique php id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, modal-dialog

I have a question regarding modals and PHP. 
I would like to open modal for unique id (depends on the link).

E.g.

```
<a href="item.php?id=1">Item1</a>
<a href="item.php?id=2">Item2</a>
<a href="item.php?id=3">Item3</a>
```

I would like to each link will open modal window but with different data(from sql database). Links also will be generated from there.

Comment: Can you clarify more on this. You want each link to open a modal dialog?  If so then you'd need to have an onclick for each link and do an Ajax request to get data from the database

Comment: yes, i need to download data from mysql via ajax, and display the correct one depending on id

Comment: This is what you'd like. Important part of your question is *what you tried*.

Answer (score 0):

In your item.php file you can get variables from url by using $_GET

You should have something like this in your item.php

```
$idLevel = $_GET['id'];
switch($idLevel){
   case 1:
       //Stuff if ID= 1
       break;
   case 2:
       //Stuff if ID= 2
       break;
   case 3:
       //Stuff if ID= 3
       break;
}
```

Comment: i know how to make it by GET, the question is how to make it with modal (single page website)

Comment: I think you can handle this and recycle part of my code using ajax and JQuery

Answer (score 0):

It is better to call your service API. So you can just send id by JavaScript and the server side will return data connected with the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:
I think example 4 will fix my problem. I will generate items with GET and just open this page with modal :)
http://jquerymodal.com/